# switch statements in C++

Tags: c++, switch-statement, c++17

What is the difference between following two code snippets of switch statement?

Which one is better? When can I use both of them?

**case 1:**

```
int i = 10;
switch(i)
{
//case
}
```

**case 2:**

```
switch(int i = 10, i)
{
//case
}
```

In second case, C++17 permitted to initialize variables inside the switch statement.

Comment: Does the case 2 compile? https://wandbox.org/permlink/DyHw98R9ErY0h5Kx

Comment: you mean `switch(int i = 10; i)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first version `i` lives past the `switch`'s scope end. You can use it should you need `i` later. You can use the second version if your compiler knows C++17.

Comment: The seconde case is invalid before C++17? i.e. It's valid since C++17?

Comment: @songyuanyao: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0305r1.html though the syntax appears to be `switch(int i = 10; i)`, i.e using a semicolon rather than a comma.

Comment: @Hasturkun Thanks for clarification. So since C++17 `switch(int i = 10; i)` becomes valid. Anyway it has nothing to do with `,`. I just can't get the point of the question (and this answer) at all.

Answer (score 3):

`switch (int i = 42; i)` is C++17 and would restrict the scope of `i` to the switch, it would be mostly equivalent to:

```
// Code before switch
{ // Additional scope
    int i = 42;
    switch (i) {
    // case...
    }
}
// Code after switch
```

It would also apply to `if`

```
if (int i = 42; i == foo()) {
    // Can use i
} else {
    // Can use i
}
```